# Creating two new columns from two different columns in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a df in this format where I have the same items with different associated data (fieldID) and the values (value).

| itemID | fieldID | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Title |
| 1 | 6 | 2019 - 03 - 00 |
| 2 | 1 | Title 2 |
| 2 | 6 | May 26, 2020 |
| 3 | 1 | Title 3 |
| 3 | 6 | March 2019 |

And what I would like to do is create a table like this instead

| itemID | Date | Title |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019 - 03 - 00 | Title |
| 2 | May 26, 2020 | Title 2 |
| 3 | March 2019 | Title 3 |

Not sure how to try this. I have been looking at the mutate function and googling creating new columns based on condition, but need some additional help...

Comment: Check out the `spread` function eg tutorial for long to wide transformations: https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/282405_e280f5f0073544d7be417cde893d78d0.html

Comment: Why not write up a solution based on `spread` ? It should be a fairly good learning experience, and a nice additional option to the other possible answers presented

Comment: great, thank you for the resource. I didn't know about this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recode the values 1 to 'Title' and 6 to 'Date' and cast the data in wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(fieldID = recode(fieldID, '1' = 'Title', '6' = 'Date')) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = fieldID, values_from = value)

#  itemID Title   Date          
#   <int> <chr>   <chr>         
#1      1 Title   2019 - 03 - 00
#2      2 Title 2 May 26, 2020  
#3      3 Title 3 March 2019
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(itemID = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), fieldID = c(1L, 
6L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 6L), value = c("Title", "2019 - 03 - 00", "Title 2", 
"May 26, 2020", "Title 3", "March 2019")), 
row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% select(-fieldID) %>% filter(row_number()%%2 == 0 ) %>% inner_join(
 df %>% select(-fieldID) %>% filter(row_number()%%2 != 0 ), by = 'itemID'
 ) %>% select(itemID, 'Date' = value.x, 'Title' = value.y)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  itemID Date           Title  
   <dbl> <chr>          <chr>  
1      1 2019 - 03 - 00 Title  
2      2 May 26, 2020   Title 2
3      3 March 2019     Title 3
```

Data used:

```
df
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  itemID fieldID value         
   <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>         
1      1       1 Title         
2      1       6 2019 - 03 - 00
3      2       1 Title 2       
4      2       6 May 26, 2020  
5      3       1 Title 3       
6      3       6 March 2019
```